# Active Record model with same name of an ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In order to separate thing, I want to have a class Order and a model Order. Here my classes :

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and

```
class Order
end
```

How can I achieve this ? Is there a trick ?

I don't want to do this :

```
module Something
    class Order
    end
end
```

I prefer to have an other name for the model rather that the change the name of my bussiness class (Order)

**Note**

If you know the "clean architecture" principle, by Bob C. Martin, this is why I try to do this.

**Edit :**

I found a way, but not sure if the cleanest way :

```
class OrderInDb < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "orders"
end
```

Comment: You can't have two different classes with the same name in one scope. When you write `Order` in your application which of the two classes do you expect to refer to?

Comment: If you really wanted the same name(ish) for what I am going to assume is a service object of sorts you could name space it with the AR class e.g. `class Order < ApplicationRecord; class Order; end; end;` then your "service object" would be `Order::Order` (but it definitely reads a little funny)

Comment: The problem is inherent in ActiveRecord, it mixes both model and data persistence in the name of convenience. You might want to consider [ROM](http://rom-rb.org/4.0/learn/) which separates the model and persistence in to two distinct objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to change the underlying table name then you could do this:

```
class CustomerOrder < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'orders'
end
```

You might also want to change any associations that you have too. e.g.:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders, class_name: 'CustomerOrder', inverse_of: :customer
end
```